# Erro "must be str, not list" ao escrever em arquivo

Tags: python

Tenho um trabalho pra fazer mas não estou conseguindo achar o erro. Esse trecho do programa precisa adicionar palavras em um arquivo texto de forma acumulativa. Ou seja, toda vez que passar pelo laço vai adicionar números e palavras no arquivo texto sem apagar o que já está escrito.

O que eu fiz até agora está assim:

```
arqParcial=open("parcial.txt","r")
texto=arqParcial.readline()
f1=[]
for i in range (len(texto)):
            palavra=texto[i].split()
            f1.append(palavra)
print(f1)
arqParcial.writelines(f1)
arqParcial.close()
```

Mas fica dando esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/teste3.py", line 8, in <module>
    arqParcial.writelines(f1)
TypeError: must be str, not list
```

que eu não faço ideia do porquê.

O programa é bem mais longo. Só coloquei esse trecho pra ver se vocês conseguem me dizer o porquê do erro.

Answer (score 3):

Tem várias coisas erradas aqui. Começando por:

```
arqParcial=open("parcial.txt","r")
```

Você está abrindo o arquivo em modo somente leitura. Ou seja, não vai escrever mais adiante no seu código, o que parece ser a intenção. É preciso trocar para:

```
with open("parcial.txt", "a") as arqParcial:
    ...
```

Todo o resto que você escreveu parece não ter utilidade porque aparentemente você estava lendo para escrever novamente no arquivo. Não precisa fazer isso. É mais simples apenas escrever ao final dele, e não ler tudo pra depois escrever.

Feito isso, para escrever no arquivo, basta chamar `writeline` ou `writelines`, como você já estava fazendo.

O `close` não precisa dentro do `with`.

Sobre este erro:

> TypeError: must be str, not list

O erro é claro. Você está passando para `writelines` uma lista. A função pede `string`. Se a intenção é escrever no arquivo uma lista de `string`s, a construção a seguir é mais adequada:

```
for linha in f1:
    arqParcial.writeline(linha)
```

Comment: Entendi. Mas ai então eu nao consigo ler oq tem no arquivo, nao? Fica dando esse erro agora de not readable. Ou eu posso com o 'a' escrever diretamente que nao vai apagar oq ja esta la?

Comment: Exato. Append (ou simplesmente "a") escreve tudo ao final do arquivo. Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Consegui aqui! Muito obrigada! Aliás, funciona pra adicionar uma matriz também?

Comment: Funciona sim. [Veja aqui como funciona o fluxo de um site de perguntas e respostas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Obrigado!