# Como utilizar arquivos em python

Tags: python, sistema-de-arquivos

Ainda estou terminando um programa como trabalho de prog I e estou com muita dificuldade na parte de arquivos.
Não estou conseguindo inserir uma matriz no arquivo. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

O programa se trata sobre o jogo de Einstein, e tem que ter as seguintes exigências na parte de arquivos:

> Opção 3: Imprimir em um arquivo texto um relatório com histórico das
> jogadas(palavras e posições preenchidas), além da matriz atualizada e
> da pontuação(número de acertos), para cada jogador cadastrado.
>
> O Arquivo também deverá conter o número médio de jogadas entre os jogadores para obter o sucesso (completar a matriz), bem como, qual jogador completou a matriz com o menor número de jogadas e aquele com o maior número de jogadas.
>
> Após a conclusão do relatório, informar ao usuário o nome do arquivo texto gerado.

O programa por enquanto está assim: (exclui o que nao é necessario para arquivos, como a matriz resultado)

```
arqParcial=open("parcial.txt","w")
arqParcial.write("Relatório de Jogadas: \n")
arqParcial.write("Coluna / Alteração\n")
arqParcial.close()
matriz=[]
for i in range (6):
    linha=['-']*6
    matriz.append(linha)
matriz[0][0]=':D'
matriz[0][1]='Casa 1'
matriz[0][2]='Casa 2'
matriz[0][3]='Casa 3'
matriz[0][4]='Casa 4'
matriz[0][5]='Casa 5'
matriz[1][0]= '1.Cor'
matriz[2][0]= '2.Nacionalidade'
matriz[3][0]= '3.Bebida'
matriz[4][0]= '4.Cigarro'
matriz[5][0]= '5.Animal'
for i in range(6):
    print(matriz[i])

print('') 
print('Dicas: \nO Norueguês vive na primeira casa. \nO Inglês vive na casa Vermelha. \nO Sueco tem Cachorros como animais de estimação. \nO Dinamarquês bebe Chá. \nA casa Verde fica do lado esquerdo da casa Branca. \nO homem que vive na casa Verde bebe Café. \nO homem que fuma Pall Mall cria Pássaros. \nO homem que vive na casa Amarela fuma Dunhill. \nO homem que vive na casa do meio bebe Leite. \nO homem que fuma Blends vive ao lado do que tem Gatos. \nO homem que cria Cavalos vive ao lado do que fuma Dunhill. \nO homem que fuma BlueMaster bebe Cerveja. \nO Alemão fuma Prince. \nO Norueguês vive ao lado da casa Azul. \nO homem que fuma Blends é vizinho do que bebe Água.')
print('')
print('OBS: Digite tudo como indicado acima, incluindo os acentos.')
print('')
linha=input('Digite o número correspondente a linha que deseja alterar(1.Cor; 2.Nacionalidade; 3.Bebida; 4.Cigarro; 5.Aninal) ou Desisto ou Acabei: ')
linha=linha.upper()


while linha != 'ACABEI' and linha != 'DESISTO':
    linha=int(linha)
    coluna=int(input('Digite o número correspondente a coluna que deseja alterar (Casa 1; Casa 2; Casa 3; Casa 4; Casa 5: '))
    novo=input('Digite a alteração: ')
    novo=novo.lower()
    matriz[linha][coluna]=novo
    visu=input('Deseja visualizar a tabela (S ou N)? ')
    visu=visu.upper()
    with open("parcial.txt", "a") as arqParcial:
        arqParcial.writelines(str(coluna)+ "  /  ")
        arqParcial.writelines(str(novo)+"\n")
        for i in range(6):
            arqParcial.writelines(matriz[i])
    if visu == 'S':
        for i in range(6):
            print(matriz[i])
```

Porém nessa parte:

```
for i in range(6):
            arqParcial.writelines(matriz[i])
```

Dá erro.
Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Erro "must be str, not list" ao escrever em arquivo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/117140/erro-must-be-str-not-list-ao-escrever-em-arquivo)

Comment: Sem a manesagem de erro que dá as vezes fica dificil responder . A mensagem de erro normalemente também diz exatamente o que está errado nesses casos.

Answer (score 2):

A primeira vista, não há problema no programa que justificasse um erro na linha que você indica - mas há vários outros problemas na construção do programa, que vão fazer com que ele não funcione como se planeja, e podem levar a erros nesse ou em outros lugares.

Já uqe você teve um problema no método `writelines` começo por aí: esse método é usado quando se deseja passar um iterável - por exemplo, uma lista de strings - para serem gravadas consecutivamente no arquivo. Por coincidência ele funciona quando você passa uma única string também - por que o Python considera uma string como um interável de strings de uma única letra - ou seja, quando você escreve: `arqParcial.writelines(str(coluna)+ "  /  ")`o Python resolve a expressão entre parênteses, que resulta em uma string do tipo "1 / " - e o writelines escreve no arquivo os caracteres "1", " ", "/" e " ", como se cada um fosse uma linha. Nesses casos, o mehor é usar o método `write` do arquivo, não `writelines`.

Na linha que você indica, o uso de writelines seria correto - mas só vai funcionar se cada elemento da lista passada para o arquivo for uma string. Se algum elemento for diferente de uma string (como um número, ou `None`), ioo writelines não faz a conversão automática para string e dá erro - por isso a mensagem de erro exata é importante.

Agora, olhando o programa, parece ser um programa feito em Python 3.x - já que você trata o valor retornado de  `input` como uma string na linha 
novo=novo.lower() ` -  e nesse caso todos os elementos da matriz seriam strings. Não deveria dar erro - apesar de eu não ter certeza se ele vai gravaro que você quer no arquivo.

Uma outtra coisa é que em Python normalmetne não se usa tanto o `for` com `range` como você faz: o `for` já retorna cada elemento de uma sequência - então, exceto o primeiro `for` onde você cria a sua matriz, todos os outros podem ser trocados de algo como:

```
for i in range(6):
    print(matriz[i])
```

para

```
for linha in matriz:
    print (linha)
```

Não há a necessidade de uma variável auxiliar de índice.

Como eu disse, são algumas dicas - mas sem a mensagem de erro que você tem, não dá para saber por que o programa para nessa linha especificamente.